# Can not write variable to any file in bash scripting using ~ in path?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm writing bash script to automate java 8 installation and setting up home variable. Its a part of a big automation script.

I have completed everything and able to print path of home variable. But I can't seem to write or append in any file when I'm using ~ in the path.

**Example**

Not work: echo "$writeit" >> ~/.bashrc
Works: echo "$writeit" >> /home/geek/.bashrc

Output of my script states empty JAVA_HOME variable
[image: Output]

These commands works perfect if I indivisibly run in terminal.
[image]

CODE

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE="java.log"
touch $LOG_FILE
exec > >(tee $LOG_FILE) 2>&1
echo "Java Installation Succeded"
echo $JAVA_HOME
javapath=$(ls -l `which java` | grep -oP "(?<=\-\>\s)(.*)")
javahome=$(ls -l ${javapath} | grep -oP "(?<=\-\>\s\/)(.*)(?=bin)")
writeit="export JAVA_HOME=${javahome}"
echo "$writeit"
echo "$writeit" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
echo 'JAVA_HOME is set'"${JAVA_HOME}"
```

Comment: Code provided should be a [mre] -- the *shortest possible code* that demonstrates a specific problem. If someone has to dig through a bunch of unrelated code to get to where you're trying to "write or append in any file", that makes your question unnecessarily hard to answer.

Comment: ...I mean, yes, you're showing us code that tries to append to `~/.bashrc`, but then you aren't providing any proof that it didn't work.

Comment: (BTW, what's the purpose of the `ls` use? Why not just `javapath=$(which java)`, for example -- or even better, `javapath=$(command -v java)`, which is -- unlike `which` -- guaranteed to be built into all POSIX-compliant shells?)

Comment: BTW, do also note that `source ~/.bashrc` in a script runs those commands *inside the script*, but doesn't run them in the shell that _called_ the script. Programs can't change their parent process's environment variables, so this is normal and expected behavior.

Comment: Are you sure it's not being written? What do you see if you do `grep JAVA_HOME ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I suspect there's a conditional in `.bashrc` that skips some code in non-interactive shells, and the new line is being skipped because of this.

Comment: @Barmar, ...since the OP didn't show us how they're starting their script but only how it exits, I suppose it's conceivable that it runs in an environment that differs from their own; if `HOME=/` in the script's environment, then `~/.bashrc` won't refer to what they mean it to. But yes, it's more likely that `~/.bashrc` just isn't running the code at hand on account of flow control.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But since he's writing to the same file he's sourcing, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy He's sourcing `.bashrc` in the same script that's editing it, so there's no need for it to change the parent environment.

Comment: @Barmar: _I suspect there's a conditional_ : Since the new variables are appended to .bashrc, it can't be an open conditional (i.e. one branch of an `if` statement), because this would give a syntax error when sourcing it.

Comment: @FaizanSh: Since you don't mention that you get an error message when running the script, I'm absolutely sure that `echo "$writeit" >> ~/.bashrc` **does** append the line to .bashrc and although it is a bad idea to modifiy .bashrc from a script, there is no law against it. I would simply add a line `tail -n 1 /.bashrc` before sourcing it, to verify that appending has worked.

Comment: @FaizanSh: The title of your question says _Can not write variable to any file_. Why do you say **any** file, if you didn't try to write to more than one file?

Comment: Please stop converting text content into pixel content.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. Code is minimal now. I have given the proof in images where I get nothing echoing JAVA_HOME. ls -l states where the given path is pointing to (if any) I needed that.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. grep JAVA_HOME ~/.bashrc gives nothing. I tried writing in different fils and it doesn't work with ~. it needs the proper path.

Comment: @ALL It works when I give proper path but doesn't when I write ~/file. I can't get the answer why but I'm searching. Might need to change the question details

Example
Does not work : echo "$writeit" >> ~/.bashrc
Worsks: echo "$writeit" >> /home/geek/.bashrc

Comment: `~`, used unquoted, expands to the current value of `$HOME`. So check how you're running your script to ensure that `HOME` has the value you expect.

Comment: (your screenshot shows the _end_ of an invocation, but it doesn't show us how you _started_ that invocation -- and really, we [prefer that people not provide screenshots of text here at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)).

Comment: Echoing `"$JAVA_HOME"` tells us that it wasn't set by sourcing the file, but that doesn't tell us that it wasn't successfully appended to the file. If the file already contained `return`, for example, then anything appended to it will do nothing at all, even if the append was 100% successful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for all the help. I run the script with sudo and  echoing ~ in the script prints /root but when I sudo echo ~ it prints /home/geek. Is there any way I could run it under the current user?

Comment: If you want to run it under the current user, _don't use `sudo`_. Switching to a different user is what `sudo` _does_.

Comment: That said, it is possible to programmatically find the home directory of the user who ran `sudo`. There are two parts to it -- finding out who ran `sudo`, and finding the home directory of a named user -- and I'd be surprised if both those parts didn't already exist in our knowledge base.

Comment: ...that said, if they don't already exist, feel free to ask a new question focused squarely on that problem. (This has drifted pretty far from "can not write variable to any file in bash scripting").